# Unit testing a compnent that is getting data from Angular Replay Subject

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, rxjs, jasmine

I have this service called EmployeeService where I am using Angular's ReplaySubject to get data from an api. I'm subcribing to this ReplaySubject from another component which I am trying to test now. But because I'm unable to mock the data from the service mentioned above, the unit test is not working.

This is a bare bones of the EmployeeService:

```
class EmployeeService extends ApiService {

  public currentEmployeeSub: ReplaySubject<EmployeeModel> = new ReplaySubject<EmployeeModel>(1);
  private currentEmployee: EmployeeModel;
  private uuid: UuidService;

  constructor(
    auth: AuthService,
    http: HttpClient,
    uuid: UuidService
  ) {
    super('employees', auth, http);
    this.uuid = uuid;
  }

  // other methods
}
```

This is a utilService which is also being used to parse the data:

```
class UtilService {
  parse(object: any) {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object));
  }
}
```

Now this is the component I'm trying to test. Please note that this is a huge component but I'm just showing the most important part which is needed for this component to work and that is the employee data coming from EmployeeService.

```
class SalaryComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {

  private utilService: UtilService;
  private employeeService: EmployeeService;

  employee: EmployeeModel;
  employeeSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(utilService: UtilService, employeeService: EmployeeService
  ) {
    this.utilService = utilService;
    this.employeeService = employeeService;

    this.employeeSubscription = this.employeeService.currentEmployeeSub.subscribe((employee: EmployeeModel) => {
      this.employee = this.utilService.parse(employee);
    });
}
```

The above component is subscribing to ReplaySubject in EmployeeService, gets the data of the employee and sets `this.employee` after parsing the data. I just need to set the data for `this.employee` in the test spec so that I can unit test a component which relies on this data like this:

```
<div class="cb-col-12">
   <dropdown
      *ngIf="employee"
      name="employee"
      formControlName="employee"
      (handlerSelect)="onEmployeeChange($event)"
      [options]="employeeOptions"
   >
   </dropdown>
</div>
```

This is how the test spec look like:

```
describe('SalaryComponent', () => {
  let component: SalaryComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SalaryComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [],
      declarations: [],
      providers: [],
    })
      .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SalaryComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  fit('should show drop down if there is employee data', async ()  => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    await fixture.whenStable();
  
    component.employee = {
      name: 'John Doe',
      age: 23,
      qualifications: [],
      address: {},
    }

    fixture.detectChanges();
    await fixture.whenStable();

    const hostElement: HTMLElement = fixture.nativeElement;
    const dropDown: HTMLInputElement = hostElement.querySelector(
      'dropdown[name="employee"]'
    );

    expect(dropDown).toBeTruthy();
  } 
}
```

I am getting `null` for the dropdown element even when there is employee data set in the component.

How can I mock ReplaySubject to set employee data in the component so that it takes effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to mock the `EmployeeService` for it to have the data you want.

This is not a complete answer but should hopefully get you started.

Follow comments with !!:

```
describe('SalaryComponent', () => {
  let component: SalaryComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SalaryComponent>;
  // !! Declare a mock for EmployeeService
  let mockEmployeeService: jasmine.SpyObj<EmployeeService>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    // !! Assign the mock
    mockEmployeeService = jasmine.createSpyObj<EmployeeService>('EmployeeService', {}, { currentEmployeeSub: of({ /* Mock Employee model here */ } as any) });
    // !! Look into jasmine.createSpyObj, the first string argument is optional 
    // and for debugging purposes. The 2nd argument can be an object or an array
    // where you can mock public methods and the 3rd argument is an object
    // where you can mock public instance variables as we did here.
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [],
      declarations: [],
      providers: [
        // !! Provide the mock
        { provide: EmployeeService, useValue: mockEmployeeService }, 
      ],
    })
      .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SalaryComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  fit('should show drop down if there is employee data', async ()  => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    await fixture.whenStable();
  
    component.employee = {
      name: 'John Doe',
      age: 23,
      qualifications: [],
      address: {},
    }

    fixture.detectChanges();
    await fixture.whenStable();

    const hostElement: HTMLElement = fixture.nativeElement;
    const dropDown: HTMLInputElement = hostElement.querySelector(
      'dropdown[name="employee"]'
    );

    expect(dropDown).toBeTruthy();
  } 
}
```

Comment: Hello. I tried this but kind of getting a type error in 'Mock Employee Model Here'. This is the error message: `Type 'Observable<{ name: string; available: true; }>' is missing the following properties from type 'ReplaySubject<EmployeeModel>': _bufferSize, _windowTime, _timestampProvider, _buffer, and 14 more.` which doesn't even exist in my model.

Comment: You should add the `as any` type cast in the `jasmine.createSpyObj`. I have updated my answer to reflect that.